# How to stop and end a CSS transition with JavaScript using an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have this problem where I am trying to implement a simple CSS transition with javascript, where when `start` button is pressed, it would move and stop depending on the duration of the keyframe and then when `end` is clicked, it would disappear and then again reappear when start is pressed with the same animation.

Does someone know what might be the issue here? And for some reason, when the transition is over, it jumps to the corner.

```js
 function add()
  {
  document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.add("run-animation");
  }    
function remove()
  {
document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.remove("run-animation");
  }
```

```css
body{
 background-color: "#4287f5";
}

#myAnimation
{
 position:relative;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40p;
}
.run-animation 
{
 -webkit-animation: move 6s;
    animation: move 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move
{
  0%  {left: -200px;}
    25%  {left: 200px;}
    50%  {left: 100px;}
}
@keyframes move
{
 0%  {left: -200px;}
    25%  {left: 200px;}
    50%  {left: 100px;}
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="add()">Start</button> 
  <button onclick="remove()">End/Remove</button> 
   <div id="myAnimation" class="run-animation"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/23/6e17286b0e01cf2775e6fa81a07d1ae3-full.png" /></div>
```

Comment: you haven't mention in your key frame when the animation is complete i.e 100%, you could add `100% {
    left: 0;
  }`

Comment: when we are using key frames we should give complete breakpoints for given requirement. you check this link : https://codepen.io/t3veni/pen/YzzZZRO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you want a *"transition"* but are using an `animation`. If you want a transition, use a transition.

*"Yeah but how do I make it go farther than the end point?"* <sub>[someone might say.]</sub>

Use a custom [`bezier-curve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) timing function where the ordinate will be outside the [0, 1] range. Doing so this will create a bouncing effect.

From there, it's easy to control the two states of your element since you only have to change one value.

```css
#myAnimation {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  transition: transform 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.5, 3);
}
:checked ~ #myAnimation {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
body{ margin:0; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check">show elem</label>
<div id="myAnimation"></div>
```

Note: In the above example I used `transform` instead of your original `left` because for performance reasons that should be the preferred way, but that will work with any animatable property.
Also, I used a simple checkbox as the control, but you can keep your button + js to toggle a class, that will do just the same.

Comment: Hello. Your code works great. Might you know how to apply javascript to it so the transform: translate would be triggered and ended with javascript?

Comment: Use a class like you did in your own code instead of `:checked ~ #myAnimation`.

Comment: Can you check this fiddle to determine the error? https://jsfiddle.net/developingm/1p4tfv56/11/

Comment: A few things, jsfiddle by default will wrap the js code in an onload event callback, you are attaching your events through html attributes and need your callback functions to be declared in global scope, to do so, you need to set jsfiddle to "nowrap in ...". Then, #myAnimation as higher importance than .run-animation, you need to make your selector have more importance (#myAnimation.run-animation will do). Finally, if you want the transition to happen at page load, you need to toggle the class after the document has been parsed: https://jsfiddle.net/t81hd3qj/1/

Comment: I must thank you, for assisting me with this problem. Your help was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because you are not defining how your element should look when it is not animated. You can set a `display:none;` on it by default and then a `display:block;` during the animation. Here is an example:

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.add("run-animation");
}

function remove() {
  document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.remove("run-animation");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: "#4287f5";
}

#myAnimation {
  position: relative;
  /*
  Hide the element if it is not animated
  */
  display: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40p;
}

#myAnimation.run-animation {
  -webkit-animation: move 6s;
  animation: move 6s;
  /*
  Show the element if it is animated
  */
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Start</button>
<button onclick="remove()">End/Remove</button>
<div id="myAnimation" class="run-animation"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/23/6e17286b0e01cf2775e6fa81a07d1ae3-full.png" /></div>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code in a jsfiddle. Might you be able to tell what is the issue with the fiddle as it does not work at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/developingm/1p4tfv56/6/

Comment: Also, for some reason, it does not stay to 100px but jumps to 0 when everything has ended.

Comment: Here (https://jsfiddle.net/dynhcx0o/) I forked your fiddle to fix it and added some comments on what I did. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help

```js
function add()
  {
  document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.add("run-animation");
  }    
function remove()
  {
document.getElementById("myAnimation").classList.remove("run-animation");
  }
```

```css
body{
 background-color: "#4287f5";
}

#myAnimation
{
 position:relative;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40p; 
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;  
}
.run-animation 
{
 -webkit-animation: move 6s;
    animation: move 6s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move
{
 0%  {left: 0;}
    25%  {left: 200px;opacity: 1;}
    50%  {left: 100px;opacity: 0;}
    80%  {left: 0; opacity: 0;}
    100% {left: 0; opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes move
{
 0%  {left: 0;}
    25%  {left: 200px;opacity: 1;}
    50%  {left: 100px;opacity: 0;}
    80%  {left: 0; opacity: 0;
    100% {left: 0; opacity: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Start</button> 
  <button onclick="remove()">End/Remove</button> 
   <div id="myAnimation" class="run-animation"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/23/6e17286b0e01cf2775e6fa81a07d1ae3-full.png" /></div>
```